# How to get 2 records only if difference between them is more then 15 min

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to be able to find first and the second record with sql only if time between those 2 is 15 or more minutes.

Let me put a little example so you can see what I need:

```
ID| Time | Serial |   
 1| 10:45|   13   |  
 2| 11:00|   12   |  
 3| 11:17|   12   |  
 4| 11:00|   13   |  
 7| 11:05|   13   |  
 8| 11:07|   12   |
```

I need to get this lines:

```
ID| Time | Serial |
```

**`1| 10:45|   13   |`**
 **`2| 11:00|   12   |`**
 **`3| 11:17|   12   |`**
 **`4| 11:00|   13   |`**
 `7| 11:05|   13   |`
 `8| 11:07|   12   |`

And output like this:

```
Time 1 | Time 2 | Serial | Usage  
 10:45 | 11:00  | 13     | 15min
 11:00 | 11:17  | 12     | 17min
```

EDIT:
I only need to compare 2 records at the same time with the same serial number. And of course go trough all the records.
I have this type of the data in time column:`2012-09-06 16:53:05.581`

Comment: Are you open to using PHP? it's not in your tags, but would make this easier (for me, IMO)

Comment: The 'two records' in each case are with matching serial columns, right? But why not pair record 2 with record 8, since they are for the same serial? Edit: for **more** than 15 mins, right!

Comment: So... for a given serial number, will there only be two records where the times are more than 15 minutes apart? What should be done if there are three records where the times are 15 minutes apart?

Comment: @halfer number 2. and 8. have diferrence of 7 min. I need something that will take 2 variables from user for example he wants records from 15min to 45 min.

Comment: Post the query, or there's nothing to work with and this will get closed

Comment: @halfer If you have 3 in the same sequence then he shows me 1.-2. and 2.-3.

Comment: @OMGPonies I have no idea how to make this query.. I can make only that one serial has 15 min difference

Comment: @denonth - it might be useful if you were to create a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) containing a test dataset, and then people can fork it and try their own queries. Ensure that you have the three-sequence in your test data, so we can see how queries need to be modified to handle that.

Comment: Also bear in mind that, when you get a hint (such as my answer) you should be keen to try ideas of your own, rather than getting the precise answer you want. It's good practise `:)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something along these lines:

```
SELECT
    time1.time,
    time2.time,
    time1.serial,
    (time2.time - time1.time) / 60 AS usage
FROM
    mytable time1,
    mytable time2
WHERE
    time1.id != time2.id
    AND time1.serial = time2.serial
    AND time2.time - time1.time > 60 * 15
```

I am not familiar with time handling in MySQL - I am assuming that they can be subtracted, and that the difference is in seconds. Use a function here if it requires explicit conversion.

Addendum: this should handle pairs of record entries fine. However if there are three that each have 15 minutes between them, then this will produce 1-2, 2-3 and 1-3, so you may need to modify it a bit.

Comment: I have this type of the data in time column:`2012-09-06 16:53:05.581`

Comment: When specifying a type, it is usual to specify it as a string, such as `TIMESTAMP` or `DATE` or `DATETIME`. Look at your table definition in `DESCRIBE TABLE`, or in phpMyAdmin. Anyway, try my query and see if it works! If it gets stuck on the time thing, I am sure you can fix that - as I said under your question, this is good practice for you.

Comment: Yikes! Are you able to convert that to a sensible type in your table definition?

Comment: If not, you can do the conversion dynamically, though it is not ideal - use [this reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to help modify my query.

Comment: This reference manual is good but how to convert in this line: `AND time2.time - time1.time > 60 * 15`

Comment: I'll start you off: `AND STR_TO_DATE(time2.time, '(format)') - STR_TO_DATE(time1.time, '(format)') > 60 * 15` - that's presuming date columns can be subtracted. You'll need to fill in '(format)' here, details on that manual page.

Comment: I can't find where you combine date and time together. I found `'%M %d,%Y'` and `%h:%i:%s`. Can I put them together in one?

Comment: Yes, but not in that order. Look at the format of your date (2012-09-06 16:53:05.581), and then look up the "specifiers" corresponding to that format. So it will start `%Y-%m-` (for `year-month-`)... you fill in the rest. The specifiers are on the link I sent to you.

Comment: I have tried this `AND STR_TO_DATE(time2.Vrijeme, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') - STR_TO_DATE(time1.Vrijeme, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') > 1` and my query is executed and I'm not getting anything as result. And I am sure that there are records that can fit this query. Probably formatting is wrong

Comment: Experiment with `SELECT STR_TO_DATE(time2.Vrijeme, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s') FROM mytable time2 WHERE Vrijeme IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1;` first. Maybe you need a placeholder for fractional seconds?

Comment: this gives me normal output '2012-09-06 16:53:05'

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17260/discussion-between-halfer-and-denonth)