# How to get records only if difference between them is 10 sec

Tags: mysql

I need to be able to find all records with sql only if time between those less than 10 seconds.

Let me put a little example so you can see what I need:

```
id     method       db_add_date
1      5            2013-09-11 00:42:12
2      6            2013-09-11 00:42:25
3      4            2013-09-11 12:02:33
4      7            2013-09-11 12:02:35
5      1            2013-09-11 12:10:54
6      2            2013-09-11 12:10:57
```

And output like this:

```
id     method       db_add_date
3      4            2013-09-11 12:02:33
4      7            2013-09-11 12:02:35
5      1            2013-09-11 12:10:54
6      2            2013-09-11 12:10:57
```

because #3 & #4 has difference 2 seconds &
 #5 & #6 has difference 3 seconds

I am having difficulty in putting this into a SQL query form, I would appreciate any help on this!

Comment: You need to do a self join. Cannot give you answer because only have the ipad.

Comment: @Johan iPad? luxury! I have posted almost exclusively from my iPhone for the past year, including all code snippets and SQL. Quit complaining and start posting!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get 2 records only if difference between them is more then 15 min](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12608442/how-to-get-2-records-only-if-difference-between-them-is-more-then-15-min)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join the table to itself on a +/- 10 second timestamp range, making sure not to join to itself:

```
select distinct t1.*
from mytable t1
join mytable t2
  on t2.db_add_date between subdate(t1.db_add_date, interval 10 second) 
    and adddate(t1.db_add_date, interval 10 second)
  and t2.id != t1.id
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/48087/10)

Points:

- this finds near rows by joining to itself
- if rows only come in pairs within 10 seconds (not more than two within 10 seconds) you can omit the `distinct` keyword
- if an index is on `db_add_date` this will perform well and scale well due to the way the look up time interval is determibant for the joined rows